# SOQL Lookup != null condition in where clause is Selective or Non Selective?

Tags: soql, batch

I have a batch class to process some records
Select Field1, Field2 from Object where Lookup_Field__c != null && Date_Field__c in (Date1, Date2)

Now the Object that this query is on has more than 7 million records and growing. There are very few records that have Lookup_Field__c populated(about 0.1% of the total data volume)

Even though the Lookup_Field__c is indexed, as per the database query optimizer cheatsheet it is mentioned that having a != in the query filter makes the filter conditions unselective. The Date field used in the query is currently not indexed.

Hence my question is, will the above query degrade my batch class to the point of causing the query to fail? Is there a better recommended approach for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a negative filter will decrease the query performance. Please note that a filter condition with a Negative filter operator comes under Index Selectivity Exception

[image]
As per this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm)

Typically, a custom index isn’t used in these cases.

- The queried values exceed the system-defined threshold.
- **The filter operator is a negative operator such as NOT EQUAL TO (or
  !=), NOT    CONTAINS, and NOT STARTS WITH.**
- The CONTAINS operator is used in the filter, and the number of rows
  to be scanned exceeds 333,333. The CONTAINS operator requires a full
  scan of the index. This threshold is subject to change.
- You’re comparing with an empty value (Name !='').

As per Salesforce best practices we should not use negative filters. I recommend using [query plan tool](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334796&type=1&mode=1) and this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325257&type=1&mode=1) to make the query selective. Adding more filters should help

Also, note that when you create a custom index any gain you would have had by included the custom indexed field in your query filter is lost by using a negative operator like NOT EQUAL TO (!=), NOT CONTAINS and NOT STARTS WITH.